# searching an algorithm for a mirroring cyclic periodic integer range?

Tags: mirroring

I'm looking for a fast(ish) algorithm to bound an integer in a range using cyclic mirroring. Words are hard, here is an example

I have an integer i,
and an integer range [0,n], say n = 5
Now I want to transform i such that  is within the range [0,n] but using a cyclic mirror,

```
function := j = mirror(i,n)
input:
i = ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
output:
j = ...,  2,  1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,  0,  1,  2,  3,...
```

A normal periodic cycle I would do by just taking mod(i,n). And I can find the mirrored parts quite easily using integer division mod 2. However, putting it together gets really messy. I was wondering if somebody knows a clean index mirroring algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

I based my function on the triangle wave function which is the absolute value of a shifted sawtooth function.

For this wave the period is longer than n, as we go up and down. In my case, I didn't want to repeat the edge indices so my period is:

```
        p = 2 * n - 2;
```

So I used the normal mod method to create the sawtooth (shifted n to the left) and then shifted this down such that the second part becomes negative:

```
        j = abs(mod(i-n,p) - (n-2));
```

If you are using a 1 based indexing language this becomes:

```
        j = abs(mod(i-1-n,p) - (n-2)) + 1;
```